# Is there any way to simulate clamshell mode, hardware or software?

Tags: macbook-pro, closed-clamshell

The way I am setup, my MBP (2020) does not face me. I use it in clamshell mode, but it gets really hot, much hotter than when the lid is open. If the lid is open though, I lose performance because it has to run another screen. I also lose my cursor when it accidentally goes onto the screen I can't see, and is annoying when a window decides to open in the screen I can't see.

Is there a way, either software or hardware, to fool the MBP into thinking the lid is closed?

Comment: Have you tried putting magnets where the sleep sensors are?

Comment: I am also curious, why purchase a mobile computer when the intent is to use it as a desktop.  Wouldn’t a mini be a better fit?

Comment: @Allan I use my MBP in as a desktop when I'm home, but I can still take it with me when I go on trips. Hard to do that with a mini.

Comment: It’s designed to work in closed clamshell just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as you. I tried the following :

- Use the computer in ClamShell mode >> the computer gets hot quicker than if open and would decrease the CPU frequency more often (checked with the app 'Hot")

Best option so far :

- PLug to monitor but as "mirror", and turning down the brightness of Built-in Display. Also making sure the external monitor runs to native resolution. For me, it has been the best solution so far in term of CPU hog. WindowServer is much more quieter than before and now rarely run over 10% (comparing to 17-20%)